# Doctrine find() returning controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a method within my controller that takes a deserialized object from JMSSerializerBundle and returns the full object, ready to be persisted. The reason I'm doing this is to return the updated object so, when it's persisted, it doesn't reset everything to the default.

When ran, this method ends up throwing an `ErrorException` on the indicated line and puts this in my log: `Warning: ReflectionProperty::setValue() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given in C:\DevelopmentProjects\keobi-web\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata.php line 177 (uncaught exception) at C:\DevelopmentProjects\keobi-web\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ErrorHandler.php line 65`

For some reason, the `EntityManager` method `find` is returning (according to `get_class`) `DefaultController`, the controller class for this method. And the `setFieldValue` says it's NULL.

One thing that's confusing me is the `Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException` should be thrown if the entity isn't found. It's not being thrown. So, it's obviously finding the entity, not not returning it properly...

Incoming parameter `$data` is the object deserialized by JSMSerializerBundle. `$em` is definitely `EntityManager` and `$metadata` is definitely `ClassMetadata`.

I'm at a loss here. No idea how to proceed.

> protected function processEntity($data)
>   {
>       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
>       $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($data));
>       $fqcn = $metadata->getName();
>       $blankEntity = new $fqcn();
>       $id = array();
>
> ```
> $this->get('logger')->debug('Incoming object type: ' . get_class($data)); # Keobi\ModelBundle\Entity\User
> $this->get('logger')->debug('Blank entity type: ' . get_class($blankEntity)); # Keobi\ModelBundle\Entity\User
> $this->get('logger')->debug('FQCN: ' . $fqcn); # Keobi\ModelBundle\Entity\User
>
> foreach ($metadata->getIdentifierFieldNames() as $identifier)
> {
>   $id[$identifier] = $metadata->getFieldValue($data, $identifier);
>
>   if (!$id[$identifier])
>   {
>     $this->get('logger')->debug(sprintf("Identifer '%s' missing. Assuming the object is new.", $identifier));
>     return $data;
>   }
> }
>
> $entity = $em->find($metadata->getName(), $id);
>
> $this->get('logger')->debug(get_class($entity)); # Keobi\RestAPIBundle\DefaultController
>
> foreach ($metadata->getFieldNames() as $field)
> {
>   $value = $metadata->getFieldValue($data, $field);
>   $default = $metadata->getFieldValue($blankEntity, $field);
>
>   if ($value <> $default)
>   {
>     $metadata->setFieldValue($entity, $field, $value); # <- throws ErrorException
>     $this->get('logger')->debug(sprintf("Updated field '%s' in %s", $field, get_class($entity)));
>   }
> }
>
> return $entity;
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there was an issue with Doctrine2. I updated it to the latest HEAD commit of the [Github repo](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2). What puzzles me is that this method actually worked not too long ago.

Couldn't find the exact commit that fixed the issue, but, as of this writing, the commit is [93cef612701b9e8caaf43c745978cd4fbd9d4e4e](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/93cef612701b9e8caaf43c745978cd4fbd9d4e4e).

Answer (score 0):

```
$entity = $em->find($metadata->getName(), $id);
```

You need to specify Repository in which you search, like:

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('EntitiesBundle:Entity')->find(...)
```

Comment: `$em->find()` is actually a shortcut for `$em->getRepository($entity)->find()` (http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html). I *wish* it would've been that simple. I've tried it both ways.