# EntityManager getRepository, method find(id) returns controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entitymanager

My problem is that when I try to find a database record using `$em->find` method, it returns me a Controller.

Let me put an example:

`Neostat\DiagnosticoBundle\Controller\ComponentController.php`:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$diagnostico = $em->getRepository('NeostatDiagnosticoBundle:Diagnostico')->find($id);
var_dump(get_class($diagnostico));
```

It returns `Neostat\DiagnosticoBundle\Controller\ComponentController`.

But I have an entity called `Diagnostico.php` in `src/Neostat/DiagnosticoBundle/Entity/Diagnostico.php`:

```
namespace Neostat\DiagnosticoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Neostat\PacienteBundle\Entity\Paciente;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * Diagnostico
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="diagnostico")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Neostat\DiagnosticoBundle\Entity\DiagnosticoRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"nombre"}, message="Ya existe un diagnostico con ese nombre.")
 */
class Diagnostico
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
private $id;

// etc...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which version of symfony you have ?

Comment: Sorry, Symfony version 2.4.1, and think the doctrine version is the 2.2.

Comment: If the symfony version is the problem, can i do a downgrade using composer? which version do you recommend?

Comment: What do you have in DiagnosticoRepository?

Comment: Nothing, DiagnosticoRepository.php is empty.

<?php

namespace Neostat\DiagnosticoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * DiagnosticoRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class DiagnosticoRepository extends EntityRepository
{
}

Comment: How very odd. Possible duplicate, although the solution may not help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546716/doctrine-find-returning-controller? Assuming you installed the latest stable release of Symfony it suggests there is an issue with the doctrine version included. Have you tried an explicit findBy(array('id' => $id) to see if it makes a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't return the Controller (it's not possible), the reason why you think it does is the behavior of the function `get_class()`.

Quoting the [PHP documentation of the function get_class()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php): "If `object` is omitted when inside a class, the name of that class is returned.".

Basically, in your case the `find` method returns an empty value therefore the entity is not found.

When the current class is being returned by the function `get_class()` then you should try the [function gettype()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php); this function will indicate you whether the value returned is a string, an object, NULL or any other types.

Comment: Consider changing

`$diagnostico = $em->getRepository('NeostatDiagnosticoBundle:Diagnostico')->find($id);
var_dump(get_class($diagnostico));`

 with 

`$diagnostico = $em->getRepository('NeostatDiagnosticoBundle:Diagnostico')->find($id);
if(!$diagnostico) {
throw $this->createNotFoundException();
}`

Comment: That's a great advice and a good practice too, do you mind if I include your advice in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

for find doctrine database record, please using findOneById or like findOneByUser etc..

if you want to find a list, using findByField like findByType.

these is doctrine provide for default.

Comment: Actually in Doctrine 2, find and findOneById are identical.